# How to assign Ajax callback to the script

Tags: php, ajax

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script>
  function sentAjax()
    {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
        //alert(xmlhttp.readyState);
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {

        document.getElementsByName('content') = xmlhttp.responseText;

        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","resultPage.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
  </script>
  <script name="content">
     //should be assigned here
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Below is the result from "resultPage.php"

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    objTreeMenu_1.drawMenu();
    objTreeMenu_1.writeOutput();
    objTreeMenu_1.resetBranches();

</script>
```

I would like to assign the above script to the inside `<script name="content"></script>`. However, I have tired the `document.getElementsByName('content') = xmlhttp.responseText;` which is wrong.

Is there anyone can help me? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByName('content')` only returns the elements.

you should use

```
document.getElementsByName('content')[0].innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText
```